# Include textarea tynimce with dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I would like to include a textara (tynimce) in dropzone but this last give me a null value when I send.

Check it at: https://jsfiddle.net/0qoejLo2/8/

```
this.on("success", function(file,xhr, reponse){
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'msg');
```

doesn t work reponse return this

```
   Array
  (
  [file] => Array
    (
        [name] => drop.zip
        [type] => application/zip
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpLl2BoZ
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 20848
    )

 )
$_POST: 
Array
(
[email_de] => tata@titi.fr
[a] => titi@toto.com
[sujet] => bateau
[null] => 
[msg] => 
)
```

I must retrieve the contents of my message located in the msg tag in textearea if reload page post

```
 [null] => 
[msg] => <p>hghgjdmsg<br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to have an image uploaded and then put into a TinyMCE instance? Or are you just trying to send additional fields (such as TinyMCE) with your image upload?

Comment: I just try to retrieve the info of my textarea with dropzone the last one serves me already to make my file uploads

Comment: It's been a while since I used TinyMCE but I'm sure there's a third parameter in execCommand that is the actual content you're trying to insert. Perhaps that explains your NULL value.

Comment: I am looking for from my day I do not find anything you have more used your have an idea on this command am lost with all this version of tinymce

Comment: If you use the text area as a default text area (disable TinyMCE) does $_POST['msg'] get populated with the message at upload.php?

Comment: yes off course no tinymice post is good

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your "success" event hook with the following event hook in your init function (where you config your DZ).

```
this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
   formData.append("msg", tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
});
```

If I remember correctly, TinyMCE removes the textarea and replaces it with non-form markup so Dropzone's automatic field submission will miss its contents. You need to explicitly tell Dropzone that it needs to send the TinyMCE editor's contents.

The "sending" event from Dropzone happens just before it posts your data. The "success" event is called after so it is useless to use for trying to send the editor's contents.

More info at Dropzone Docs: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me since dropzone recognizes default HTML input fields and not tinyMCE DOM.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector : "#note",

    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
          $('#note').val(editor.getContent());
        });
      }
  });
```